# How do obtain a chart of cloud filtered NDVI values from Sentinel 2 imagery in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am trying to recreate a tutorial from the GEE tutorials ([this section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_07#digression:-simple-cloud-masking-for-landsat)) using sentinel 2 instead of landsat 8. I have used some code from [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301684/creating-sentinel-2-ndvi-time-series-chart-in-google-earth-engine), which returns almost exactly what I want, however following the instructions to apply cloud filtering in an answer (put `var S2 = S2.map(maskcloud1))` instead of `var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI)` [using addNDVI works, but doesn't use the cloud filter], I am getting an error.

Would anyone have any suggestions of how to address the error that I encounter?

```
//Import Geometry
var polygonCoordList = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [111.0, 0.0, 112.0, 0.0, 111.0, 1.0]
);
Map.addLayer(polygonCoordList, {}, 'polygonCoordList');
// Create image collection of S-2 imagery for the perdiod 2016-2018
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

//filter start and end date
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-10-31')

//filter according to drawn boundary
.filterBounds(polygonCoordList);

// Function to mask cloud from built-in quality band
// information on cloud
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(maskcloud1);
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); //I just changed the name of this variable ;)

// Create palettes for display of NDVI
var ndvi_pal = ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b',
'#a6d96a'];

// Create a time series chart.
var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(S2, polygonCoordList,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});

// Display.
print(plotNDVI);

// Display NDVI results on map
Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clip(polygonCoordList), {min:-0.5, max:0.9, palette: ndvi_pal}, 'NDVI');
```

The error I get from this code states
*NDVI: Layer error: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20200103T172719_20200103T173532_T13QFC):
Image.select: Pattern 'nd' did not match any bands*.
So I assume there is no 'nd' band? Is there another way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddNDVI function creates a band called ND, so if you don't apply it you can't select it (NDVI = S2.select('ND'). So it depends on what you want, below is a suggestion where you apply the cloudmask AND the ndvi function.

```
// Add NDVI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(maskcloud1).map(addNDVI);
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am getting gaps in my chart, however I assume that is because it is now no longer including the cloud filtered images. I will investigate further!