# Clipping image to feature collection and exporting as TIFF (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to clip an image by a feature collection (roi shapefile) and export it as TIFF. When I add the clipped image to Map, it shows exactly what I want with only values inside the roi showing. But when I export it to GeoTIFF, it clips the image to bounding box of the roi rather than actual roi borderlines.

```py
IMERG = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06').first().select('precipitation')
clip = IMERG.clipToCollection(roi)  #roi is a feature collection
geemap.ee_export_image(clip, filename='test2.tif', scale=11132, region=roi.geometry())
```

This is what it exports
[image: This is what it exports]

This is what I would like (obtained by clipping the exported image by country shapefile again in QGIS).
[image: This is what I would like]

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299179/gee-export-image-todrive-output-not-matching-bounding-box) question also asks pretty much the same thing but don't seem to have a proper answer to this issue although an answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.clip()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-clip) should work

```py
import json

## load geojson of region of interest
gjson_path = r"C:\Users\Matt\Documents\roi.geojson"

with open(gjson_path) as f:
    gjson = json.load(f)

## get gjson features
features = gjson['features']

## make Earth Engine FeatureCollection of features
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(features)

## get image
IMERG = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06').first().select('precipitation')

## clip image
clip = IMERG.clipToCollection(fc)  # fc is a feature collection

## export result
region = fc.geometry()
scale = 50
folder = 'test folder'
img_name = 'test_img'

export_config = {'scale': scale, 'maxPixels': 1.0E13, 'driveFolder': folder, 'region': region}

task = ee.batch.Export.image(clip, img_name, export_config)
task.start()
```

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Don't think there is much difference between these two anyway, clipToCollection is for more complex geometries.

Comment: `.clip()` is what I use and it works as expected, but then I don't use the geemap wrapper.

does removing `.geometry()` from `roi.geometry()` work? Perhaps it is exporting with regards to the bounding box, rather than the features themselves.

Comment: `roi` is a FeatureCollection but the export function requires `Geometry` object. That is why I did `roi.geometry` . The other question I linked to also gets the same results although done from GEE code editor so don't think there's any problem in geemap.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code I used to clip with a feature collection and export to Drive.  I wonder then if your issue is caused by how your feature collection was constructed.

Comment: hmmm.. the feature collection I used is actually a shapefile of country map. I used the following code to convert it into a feature collection:

`shp = '/MyDrive/country.shp'

roi = geemap.shp_to_ee(shp)`

Comment: I have added making a feature collection from a GeoJSON to the workflow. Hopefully this works for you, if you export your shapefile to GeoJSON, using QGIS or similar